# Selenium and Java: Unable to use DesiredCapabilities.x()

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

I've been trying to use this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-selenium-with-junit-and-testng

However, I'm completely unable to use DesiredCapabilities, no matter what Selenium libraries I import.

The code example:

```
public SeleniumConfig() {
    Capabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

When I try adding the .firexfox() (org .chrome()), I get the error:

```
 Cannot resolve method 'chrome' in 'DesiredCapabilities'
```

I've added every Selenium library immaginable, as per other answers to similar questions here and other places, but nothing seems to do the trick.

When I start typing "DesiredCapabilities.", the only options I get are "class" and "new".